# How to add permissions to manifest file (Java Applet)

Tags: java, applet

Hello I wrote a java applet and it asks permissions such as:

```
javax.smartcardio.CardPermission

java.lang.RuntimePermission
```

so where is this manifest file and how can I add these permissions to it?

Comment: so I guess I found the manifest file (manifest.mf). It is located under my project. Does anyone know how to add these permissions to it?

Answer (score 2):

> ..where is this manifest file..

That is irrelevant to the stated goal, since..

> ..and how can I add these permissions to it?

..an applet either is digitally signed or not digitally signed.  If it is digitally signed, it can request that the security sand-box be relaxed.  There are two other security levels, one of which is only available to apps. deployed using JWS, the other is `all-permissions`.

This applet will require `all-permissions` - so the applet needs to be digitally signed, and the end user needs to accept the code when prompted.

Any changes required in the manifest will be done automatically by the SDK tools.  There is no point or benefit to editing it by hand.